# Duplicate insertion when saving model with has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, duplicates

In the example below saving a model results in duplicate insertions.

```
shipment_params = {name: "Guy", from_country: "US", from_city: "a Ferry", from_state: "NY", from_postal_code: "11232-1716", from_street_address: "Broadway, 1", to_country: "US", to_city: "idge", to_state: "MA", to_postal_code: "01234-5678", to_street_address: "Massachusetts Avenue, 1234", service_code: "GROUND"} 
shipment = Shipment.new(shipment_params)
shipment.save!

class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shippings
  has_many :orders, :through => :shippings
end

class Shipping < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :shipment
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shippings
  has_many :transactions #, :class_name => "OrderTransaction"
  has_many :shipments, :through => :shippings
end
```

The following SQL is shown:

```
irb(main):014:0> @shipment.save
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `shipments` (`name`, `from_country`, `from_city`, `from_state`, `from_postal_code`, `from_street_address`, `to_country`, `to_city`, `to_state`, `to_postal_code`, `to_street_address`, `service_code`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('121', 'US', 'ds Ferry', 'NY', '33-1716', 'd, 329', 'US', 'ss', 'ss', '1234-1228', 'r Avenue, 343', 'GROUND', '2016-03-14 15:04:15', '2016-03-14 15:04:15')
  SQL (5.0ms)  INSERT INTO `orders` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2016-03-14 15:04:15', '2016-03-14 15:04:15')
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `shippings` (`shipment_id`, `order_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (3, 6, '2016-03-14 15:04:15', '2016-03-14 15:04:15')
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `shippings` (`shipment_id`, `order_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (3, 6, '2016-03-14 15:04:15', '2016-03-14 15:04:15')
   (4.1ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

What do you think?

Comment: How is that duplicated insertion, it's inserting into 3 different tables `shipment`, `orders` and `shippings`?

Comment: please see that the following line shown twice: INSERT INTO shippings (shipment_id, order_id, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (3, 6, '2016-03-14 15:04:15', '2016-03-14 15:04:15')

Comment: What's in `shipment_params`?

Comment: shipment_params = {name: "Guy", from_country: "US", from_city: "a Ferry", from_state: "NY", from_postal_code: "11232-1716", from_street_address: "Broadway, 1", to_country: "US", to_city: "idge", to_state: "MA", to_postal_code: "01234-5678", to_street_address: "Massachusetts Avenue, 1234", service_code: "GROUND"}

Comment: The odd thing is that the shippings data creates automatically and duplicated. I would rather create the shipping data myself instead of shipment.save to auto populate this data..